# delete whats inside the input while pressing a key onKeyDown Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

when I try to delete whats inside the input as soon as I press a specific key, in this case it is a letter "t" with onKeyDown, the input will be cleared, but the pressed key will remain inside the input
for example:
when I type "sort" in the input the result will be "t". the "t" will remain inside the input value but I want the input value to be cleared, although I set the state of the "term" to be "" when I press the letter "t"

```
  state = { term: ""};

  keyListener = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "t") {
      this.setState({ term: "" });
    }
  };

  onInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search-bar ui segment">
        <form className="ui form">
          <div className="field">
            <label>Search Video</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={this.state.term}
              onChange={this.onInputChange}
              onKeyDown={this.keyListener}
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because onInputChange will be called next, just call e.preventDefault to prevent that:

```
keyListener = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "t") {
      this.setState({ term: "" });
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use uncontrolled input with a ref attached to it, remove `onChange` handler and keep `onKeyDown`. You can get the value using ref

```
  state = { term: ""};
  this.input = React.createRef();

  keyListener = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "t") {
      this.setState({ term: "" });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search-bar ui segment">
        <form className="ui form">
          <div className="field">
            <label>Search Video</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              ref={this.input}
              onKeyDown={this.keyListener}
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
```